# How to develop multiple pip packages in a git project?

Tags: python, django, git, pip

I'm developing a django project, using git for code management. The main project has a number of apps as submodules, each of which can be used independently, thus are each in separate git repos. All of these apps are in development, and at least one is forked from another project. These apps are installable through pip, when cloning the repo, there are setup.py and README and so forth in the root, then the actual app in a subfolder.

If I pip install the app(s), then the working code will be in a different location to the folder under git management, so every time I change the code I'd need to `pip install` (or is there another pip command for this?) to update the code where python is looking for it

I could use `pip install -e` to prevent the above situation. However, then I would need to have each app cloned into separate folders: I can't just clone the apps into `project/apps` and  have `project/apps/foo` and `project/apps/bar` as they would both try to drop their setup.py into `project/apps`. Instead I would need to clone foo into `project/apps/foo` but then the actual code is in `project/apps/foo/foo`. This strikes me as ugly and not very django-ish.

Is there some other, prettier way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- you should either be installing these apps with `pip` or cloning the apps directly and using them. In almost every case, you will either use a submodule or pip (probably thru a requirements file) but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you really want to use is a [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) (rather than using git submodules at all) coupled with a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) for your project.

With requirements files, you can clone repos directly from a given branch or commit, for instance:

*requirements.txt:*

```
Django==1.4.1
South==0.7.6
git+git://github.com/fabric/fabric#egg=Fabric
git+git://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie.git@876c0541e2531d3b6e070ffab906f7c6e359c427#egg=django-tastypie
```

Then you can run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

You'll notice from the tastypie example that you can lock your pip install to a particular commit (fine as long as you stay in your virtualenv), which is essentially the same thing a submodule does anyway, but without cluttering your git repo or file structure with packages when they really should be installed to a separate location that you source anyway.

Comment: and if I make changes to those apps I can push them back to github?

Comment: Sure, provided they are your apps. For personal projects, I'll often fix a bug in someone's lib I'm using, submit a pull request, then point my requirements file at my forked repo until the fix gets merged upstream.

Comment: That's what setting the `egg` does: when I need to use my fork of `django-tastypie`, for instance, I change the line in the requirements file to point at my fork, but leave the `egg` the same; this effectively updates the package to whichever version you want.

Comment: Note: you'll make changes to those apps in separate repos and locations, then push them back to github before using. This means you can't easily test changes to the apps in your project -- you'll have to have separate test projects to update the apps -- but that's part of good code/repo design anyway; each of these apps should have their own test cases; if they are all going to run dependent on the central project, they shouldn't be separate repos.

Comment: The requirements file URL is broken; leads to 404 error. Please update when possible.

Comment: Updated the link